Can Riemann zeta zeros be written in the form s=14.13 + 0.5i?
Julian Havil in his book Gamma: Exploring Euler’s constant
writes (p.195):

The most striking feature [of the non-trivial zeros] is that the imaginary parts of each of the complex numbers is always 0.5.

And on Table 16.1 he gives the zeros as 14.134 + 0.5i, 21.022 + 0.5i etc.
Shouldn’t this be (0.5 + 14.134i)?
Recently, I asked a similar question, referring to this paper

p.39 but I deleted it because commenters said that this was a typo.
But Havil explicitly lists the zeros on his table 16.1 with imaginary parts as being 0.5. It is unlikely that this is a typo.

Is Havil wrong?

Yes, Havil's statements are incorrect. You are right.

Yes that's definitely a mistake

Figure $16.4$ is correct, and at page $195$ he says:"All non-trivial zeros of the Riemann zeta function lie, then, symmetrically in the interval $0<\Re(z)<1$, which is known as the critical strip....see Figure $16.4$. So at least he also has the correct statement. But then the next sentence is wrong with "imaginary parts" - very strange.

A very humiliating mistake to mix the real and the imgainary part , unbelievable ! And what is the purpose of the many digits of the real-part ? Also very strange. Probably a copy-paste of someone with no clue of the Riemann hypothesis combined with incredible carelessness.

It's not neccessarily his mistake though. Since other parts clearly implies that the real part is $1/2$, especially in page 203 where the Riemann hypothesis is stated. It's probable that someone who was in charge of this typing this part didn't know much Riemann function, and some sorts of miscommunication leading to these errors. The long numbers could be the result from someone else's computation. And to be honest if I receive a list of long numbers I'll just paste them instead of trying to count how many digits I should put there
